# delete / insert atomicity in postgres

Tags: postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

I do delete (all rows) and insert (a single row) in a transaction. Is it atomic operation?  Is it possible for a reader to see two rows in the table?  I am using default transaction isolation level (Read Committed).

Comment: It is all explained here [Transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html).

Comment: Yes, it is atomic.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction itself is atomic - other sessions querying the database while the transaction is running will see the data as it was without the delete or the insert statements, and once the transaction is committed, the single inserted row will be visible to all.